# How can I pass a string to be evaluated as positional and keyword arguments?

Tags: python

I'm using a module called `credstash`, which contains this function:

```
def getSecret(name, version="", region=None,
              table="credential-store", context=None,
              dynamodb=None, kms=None, **kwargs):
```

I want to pass a string to the function to be evaluated as positional and keyword arguments.

So I have the variable called `arg_action` with this contents:

```
TEST_CREDSTASH, table=perf-accounts-credentials-store
```

I want to do something like this:

```
credstash.getSecret(arg_action)
```

The problem is that it's grabbing the whole contents of `arg_action` instead of interpreting them as the positional argument `name` and keyword argument `table`

```
credstash.ItemNotFound: Item {'name': 'TEST_CREDSTASH, table=perf-accounts-credentials-store'} couldn't be found.
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want? I don't want to hardcode the arguments on the function because I have several `credstash` functions and each one takes different arguments

I ended up solving my problem like this:

```
def credstash_action(key_id, table_name, action, args):
    action_list = {
        "get": "getSecret",
        "getall": "getAllSecrets",
        "list": "listSecrets",
        "put": "putSecret",
        "putall": "putAllSecretsAction"
    }
    function_list = {
        "getSecret": get_credstash_secret,
        "getAllSecrets": get_all_credstash_secrets,
    }
    cred_action = action_list.get(action)
    cred_function = getattr(credstash, cred_action)
    args_string = " ".join(args)
    function_list.get(cred_action)(function=cred_function, key_id=key_id, table_name=table_name, args=args_string)


def get_credstash_secret(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs['function'](kwargs['args'], table=kwargs['table_name']))


def get_all_credstash_secrets(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs['function'](table=kwargs['table_name']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing a string to *imitate* how one would normally pass arguments to a function will not work, as you observed.

Pass separate key-value pairs from your `arg_action` dictionary into the appropriate arguments to the `credstash.getSecret` function.

```
credstash.getSecret(arg_action['name'], table=arg_action['table'])
```

Comment: The problem is that I have quite a bit more functions on credstash and I don't want to have to write the arguments to each function since they're different. That's why I wanted to have a variable that can change the paramters.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, passing a string as you tried will not work, as you observed. The "right" and probably most readable way to achieve what you want is the way I have suggested. If you need to do this in several places in your code, then consider writing a wrapper function to handle it for you.

Comment: Is there a way I can call a function from a string name then? I have something like

    function_list = {
        "getSecret": 'get_credstash_secret'
    }
    func = function_list.get(action_list.get(action))
    func()

Comment: You'll need to properly format your example code. Please add it to your original question

Comment: @mormaii2 You store a reference to the function itself, not its name, in the dict. `function_list = { 'getSecret': get_credstash_secret }; function_list['getSecret']()` calls the function `get_credstash_secret`..

Answer (score 0):

You can store the positional arguments in a list and the keyword arguments in a dict, then pass each set individually.

```
pos_args = ['TEST_CREDSTASH']
kw_args = dict(table="perf-accounts-credentials-store")

credstash.getSecret(*pos_args, **kw_args)
```

The list and dictionary can themselves be elements of a single list or tuple:

```
args = (['TEST_CREDSTASH'], {"table": "perf-accounts-credentials-store"})

credstash.getSecret(*args[0], **args[1])
```